# When do we force people not to behave like Sedom

Tags: halacha-theory

<sup>Inspired by [DonielF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9682/donielf)'s comment *(Further, there are very limited cases in which we apply כופין על מדת סדום. Just because it’s זה נהנה וזה לא חסר doesn’t mean that we can force him to give his stuff.)* to [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91869/501) of *Can one coerce someone to donate a mitzvah item that he is not using?*</sup>

The Talmud occasionally refers to the concept of  כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם, yet we find it used rarely in practical Halacha.

**כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם** means **we force people to not behave like they did in Sedom** - i.e. if Ploni has nothing to lose and Almoni has everything to gain - זֶּה נֶהֱנֶה וְזֶה אֵינוֹ חָסֵר  - then we (Bet Din, I assume) force Ploni to give in to Almoni's demand.

**What are the parameters of when  כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם is used?**

---

Source material:

**Rambam** mentions it in 2 locations, both in ספר קנין, from what I can find:

1. In  [כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם in הלכות שכנים - פרק שביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02036.html#HtmpReportNum0048_L2)

> ח מִי שֶׁהָיוּ לוֹ חַלּוֹנוֹת לְמַטָּה בְּכָתְלוֹ וּבָא חֲבֵרוֹ לִבְנוֹת בִּפְנֵיהֶן וְאָמַר לוֹ אֲנִי אֶפְתַּח לְךָ חַלּוֹנוֹת אֲחֵרוֹת בְּכֹתֶל זֶה עַצְמוֹ לְמַעְלָה מֵאֵלּוּ הֲרֵי זֶה מְעַכֵּב עָלָיו וְאוֹמֵר לוֹ בְּעֵת שֶׁתִּפְתַּח הַחַלּוֹנוֹת תַּרְעִיד אֶת הַכֹּתֶל וּתְקַלְקֵל אוֹתוֹ. וַאֲפִלּוּ אָמַר אֲנִי אֶסְתֹּר כָּל הַכֹּתֶל וְאֶבְנֶה אוֹתוֹ לְךָ חָדָשׁ וְאֶעֱשֶׂה בּוֹ חַלּוֹנוֹת לְמַעְלָה וְאֶשְׂכֹּר לְךָ בַּיִת שֶׁתָּדוּר בּוֹ עַד שֶׁאֶבְנֶה יָכוֹל לְעַכֵּב עָלָיו וְאוֹמֵר לוֹ אֵין רְצוֹנִי שֶׁאֶטְרַח מִמָּקוֹם לְמָקוֹם. לְפִיכָךְ אִם לֹא הָיָה שָׁם טֹרַח כְּלָל וְאֵין צָרִיךְ לִפְנוֹת אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְעַכֵּב עָלָיו. וְכוֹפִין אוֹתוֹ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה חֲבֵרוֹ סוֹתֵם חַלּוֹן זֶה שֶׁלְּמַטָּה מִמֶּנּוּ וְעוֹשֶׂה לוֹ חַלּוֹן מִלְּמַעְלָה **שֶׁזּוֹ מִדַּת סְדוֹם**. וְ**כֵן כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁזֶּה נֶהֱנֶה בּוֹ וְאֵין חֲבֵרוֹ מַפְסִיד וְאֵין חָסֵר כְּלוּם כּוֹפִין עָלָיו**:‏

2. In [הלכות שכנים - פרק שנים עשר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02036.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2)

> א הָאַחִין אוֹ הַשֻּׁתָּפִין שֶׁבָּאוּ לַחֲלֹק אֶת הַשָּׂדֶה וְלִטּל כָּל אֶחָד חֶלְקוֹ. אִם הָיְתָה כֻּלָּהּ שָׁוָה וְאֵין שָׁם מָקוֹם טוֹב וּמָקוֹם רַע אֶלָּא הַכּל אֶחָד חוֹלְקִין לְפִי הַמִּדָּה בִּלְבַד. וְאִם אָמַר [א] אֶחָד מֵהֶם תְּנוּ לִי חֶלְקִי מִצַּד זֶה כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא סָמוּךְ לְשָׂדֶה אַחֵר שֶׁלִּי וְיִהְיֶה הַכּל שָׂדֶה אַחַת שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ [ב] **וְכוֹפֶה אוֹתוֹ עַל זֶה שֶׁעִכּוּב בְּדָבָר זֶה מִדַּת סְדוֹם הִיא**. אֲבָל אִם הָיָה חֵלֶק אֶחָד מִמֶּנָּה טוֹב אוֹ קָרוֹב לַנָּהָר יוֹתֵר אוֹ קָרוֹב לַדֶּרֶךְ וְשָׁמוּ אוֹתָהּ הַיָּפֶה כְּנֶגֶד הָרַע וְאָמַר תְּנוּ לִי בְּשׁוּמָא שֶׁלִּי מִצַּד זֶה אֵין שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ אֶלָּא נוֹטֵל בְּגוֹרָל. אָמַר לָהֶם תְּנוּ לִי (בְּשׁוּמָא שֶׁלִּי מִצַּד זֶה) חֲצִי מִדָּתָהּ מִן הַצַּד הָרַע בְּלֹא שׁוּמָא וְטל אַתָּה מִן הַצַּד הַטּוֹב כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּהְיֶה חֶלְקִי סָמוּךְ לַשָּׂדֶה שֶׁלִּי. הוֹרוּ מִקְצָת הַגְּאוֹנִים שֶׁשּׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ. וְלָזֶה דַּעְתִּי נוֹטָה וְכֵן רָאוּי לָדוּן:‏

Shulchan Aruch and/or Remo mention it a few times in Choshen Mishpot - for example:

1. In [סימן קעד - אחים או שתפים או בכור שבאים לחלק](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_16.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2)

> **א** הָאַחִין אוֹ הַשֻּׁתָּפִין שֶׁבָּאוּ לַחֲלֹק הַשָּׂדֶה וְלִטֹּל כָּל אֶחָד חֶלְקוֹ, אִם הָיְתָה כֻּלָּהּ שָׁוָה לְגַמְרֵי, חוֹלְקִין לְפִי הַמִּדָּה בִּלְבַד. וְאִם אָמַר אֶחָד: תְּנוּ לִי חֶלְקִי מִצַּד זֶה כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא סָמוּךְ לְשָׂדֶה אַחֵר שֶׁלִּי וְיִהְיֶה הַכֹּל שָׂדֶה אֶחָד, שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ, **וְכוֹפֶה אוֹתוֹ עַל זֶה, שֶׁעִכּוּב בְּדָבָר זֶה מִדַּת סְדוֹם הִיא**. ‏
>   
> *וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאֵין שׁוֹמְעִין (א) לוֹ, אֶלָּא צָרִיךְ לְהַעֲלוֹת בְּדָמִים עַד שֶׁיִּתְרַצּוּ חֲבֵרָיו (טוּר בְּשֵׁם הָרֹא''שׁ), וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּהָוֵי (ב) סָפֵק, וְכֹל דְּאַלִּים גָּבַר (מָרְדְּכַי סוֹף פֶּרֶק קַמָּא דְּב''ב בְּשֵׁם מַהֲרַ''ם)*‏
>    . אֲבָל אִם הָיָה חֵלֶק מִמֶּנָּה טוֹב, אוֹ קָרוֹב לַנָּהָר יוֹתֵר, אוֹ קָרוֹב לַדֶּרֶךְ, וְשָׁמוּ אוֹתָהּ הַיָּפֶה כְּנֶגֶד הָרָע, וְאָמַר: תְּנוּ לִי בַּשּׁוּמָא שֶׁלִּי מִצַּד זֶה, אֵין (ג) שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ, אֶלָּא נוֹטֵל בְּגוֹרָל. אָמַר לָהֶם: תְּנוּ בַּשּׁוּמָא שֶׁלִּי מִצַּד זֶה חֲצִי מִדָּתָהּ מֵהַצַּד הָרַע, וְטֹל אַתָּה מֵהַצַּד הַטּוֹב, כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא חֶלְקִי סָמוּךְ לְשָׂדֶה שֶׁלִּי, שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ. ‏
>   
> *הגה: הָיוּ בְּכָאן שְׁנֵי שָׂדוֹת, הָאֶחָד אוֹמֵר לַחֲלֹק כָּל שָׂדֶה וְשָׂדֶה, וְהָאֶחָד אוֹמֵר לַחֲלֹק שָׂדֶה כְּנֶגֶד שָׂדֶה, שׁוֹמְעִין לְזֶה שֶׁאוֹמֵר לַחֲלֹק שָׂדֶה כְּנֶגֶד שָׂדֶה. וְדַוְקָא שֶׁשְּׁתֵּיהֶן שָׁווֹת וְאֵין נַפְקוּתָא בַּחֲלֻקַּת הַשָּׂדוֹת לַחֲצָאִין, אֲבָל אִם הָאֶחָד טוֹבָה בְּשׁוּם צַד, אוֹ שֶׁאֶחָד יֵשׁ לוֹ (ד) מֶצֶר אֵצֶל הַשָּׂדוֹת, חוֹלְקִין כָּל שָׂדֶה לִשְׁנַיִם (טוּר ס''ג)*.‏

2. He hints at it in the next Se'if

> **ב** הַבְּכוֹר שֶׁחָלַק, נוֹטֵל ב' חֲלָקִים שֶׁלּוֹ (ה) כְּאֶחָד. אֲבָל (ו) הַיָּבָם שֶׁחָלַק עִם אֶחָיו בְּנִכְסֵי הָאָב, נוֹטֵל חֶלְקוֹ וְחֵלֶק אָחִיו בְּגוֹרָל; אִם עָלוּ בְּמָקוֹם אֶחָד, עָלוּ, וְאִם עָלוּ בִּשְׁנֵי מְקוֹמוֹת, עָלוּ. ‏
>   
> *הגה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּדַוְקָא שֶׁהָיוּ הַחֲלָקִים שָׁוִים, אֲבָל אִם הָיָה אֶחָד טוֹב מֵחֲבֵרוֹ, אֲפִלּוּ (ז) בְּכוֹר אֵינוֹ נוֹטֵל חֶלְקוֹ בְּיַחַד. וְכֵן אִם הָיָה לַפָּשׁוּט שָׂדֶה בְּמֶצֶר (ח) אֵלּוּ הַשָּׂדוֹת (טוּר וְהָרֹא''שׁ וְהַמַּגִּיד פי''ב דִּשְׁכֵנִים בְּשֵׁם שְׁאָר מְפָרְשִׁים).‏*

3. And again - in the Remo - in Se'if 4

> ד ב' שֶׁקָּנוּ שָׂדֶה בְּשֻׁתָּפוּת, אֶחָד שְׁלִישׁ וְאֶחָד ב' שְׁלִישִׁים, כְּשֶׁחוֹלְקִים נוֹטֵל ב' שְׁלִישִׁים בְּיַחַד, כֵּיוָן שֶׁקָּנוּ אוֹתָהּ כְּאֶחָד. אֲבָל ג' שֶׁקָּנוּ שָׂדֶה בְּשֻׁתָּפוּת, וְשׁוּב קָנָה הָאֶחָד חֵלֶק חֲבֵרוֹ, כֶּשֶׁבָּאִים לַחֲלֹק אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל (יא) לָכֹף אֶת חֲבֵרוֹ שֶׁיִּתֵּן לוֹ שְׁנֵי חֲלָקִים בְּיַחַד, כֵּיוָן שֶׁשְּׁנֵי הַחֲלָקִים לֹא הָיוּ מִתְּחִלָּה שֶׁלּוֹ, אֶלָּא בָּא מִכֹּחוֹ וּמִכֹּחַ אָחִיו שֶׁקָּנָה מִמֶּנּוּ שְׁלִישׁ. 
>   
> *הגה: שְׁנֵי אַחִין שֶׁמֵּתוּ, וּלְכָל אֶחָד שְׁנֵי בָּנִים, וּבָאִין לַחֲלֹק הַשָּׂדֶה שֶׁהָיָה שֶׁל אֲבִיהֶן, וּב' הַבָּנִים שֶׁל אֶחָד מֵהֶן רוֹצִים לִהְיוֹת שֻׁתָּפִין, וְהָאֲחֵרִים רוֹצִים לַחֲלֹק, חוֹלְקִין הַשָּׂדֶה לְד' חֲלָקִים, וְנוֹתְנִים לְאֵלּוּ הַשְּׁנַיִם חֶלְקָן בְּיַחַד, וְלַאֲחֵרִים כָּל אֶחָד לְבַדּוֹ (רַבֵּנוּ יְרוּחָם נכ''ו ח''ב) . אֲבָל אִם הָיוּ מִתְּחִלָּה ד' אַחִין, שֶׁלֹּא בָּאוּ הַשְּׁנַיִם מִכֹּחַ אֶחָד, אֵין נוֹתְנִין לָהֶם חֶלְקָן בְּיַחַד (מָרְדְּכַי פֶּרֶק שְׁנֵי דַיָּנֵי גְּזֵרוֹת בְּשֵׁם מוהר''ם) . וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דַּאֲפִלּוּ בִּכְהַאי גַּוְנָא נוֹתְנִין לָהֶן בְּיַחַד, **דְּכוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם** (כֵּן מַשְׁמָע מֵרַבֵּנוּ יְרוּחָם הַנַּ''ל).*‏

4. In the Remo in [סימן קנג - דין הוצאת זיז ומרזב והעמדת סלם ונעיצת קורות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_14.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **ח** וְכֵן אִם רָצָה בַּעַל הֶחָצֵר לִבְנוֹת תַּחַת (יג) הַצִּנּוֹר, אֵין בַּעַל הַגַּג יָכוֹל לְעַכֵּב עָלָיו, שֶׁאֵין הַצִּנּוֹר עָשׂוּי לְתַשְׁמִישׁ כְּזִיז, כְּדֵי שֶׁיַּחֲזִיק בַּאֲוִיר הֶחָצֵר, שֶׁאֵינוֹ עָשׂוּי אֶלָּא לְקִלּוּחַ הַמַּיִם. ‏
>   
> *הגה: וְהוֹאִיל וְאֵין עָלָיו אֶלָּא לְקַבֵּל מֵימָיו, אִם יִרְצֶה לְקַבְּלָם בִּכְלִי אוֹ בְּצִנּוֹר, הַדִּין עִמּוֹ (טוּר סט''ו בְּשֵׁם הרמ''ה וְנ''י בְּשֵׁם רַשְׁבָּ''ם פֶּרֶק חֶזְקַת הַבָּתִּים) . אֲבָל לֹא יוּכַל לוֹמַר לְבַעַל הַצִּנּוֹר לְהַטּוֹתוֹ לְרוּחַ אַחֶרֶת אוֹ לְשַׁנּוֹת בּוֹ כְּלָל. וַאֲפִלּוּ אִם הוּא אָרֹךְ אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְקַצְּרוֹ, וְהוּא שֶׁיֵּשׁ קְפִידָה לְבַעַל הַצִּנּוֹר, אֲבָל בְּלָאו הָכִי **כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם**, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיְּקַלְּחוּ מֵימָיו יָפֶה (כָּל זֶה בַּטּוּר).*‏

Searching for מדת סדום often shows the commentators mentioning that we do **not** use it in *this case*. **What are the parameters of when  כּוֹפִין עַל מִדַּת סְדוֹם is used?**

Comment: [Orach Chaim 386:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.386.9)

Comment: [Am I on-topic?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/9682)